# Python + webapp2 + Modify the URL without reloading the page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This question was intended for an answer that is fully python. NOT JS. That's why it is not a duplicate.

I'm using GAE and python, and I been looking for a way to change the URL in the browser from

`www.example.com/foo.html`

to

`www.example.com/banana`

without reloading the page.
it looked more straightforward in JS and Java, but I haven't found a way in python yet.

**Note:**
It would be better if there is a way through `app.yaml`. Meaning that, send a request from the handler with a pattern that goes thro `app.yaml -> main.app` and from there it gets handled by a different handler

Comment: post this as an answer ... let the world know ... let the questioning stop

Comment: @GAEfan... We are talking about Python not js

Comment: You can't do it with Python because you would need to do it client side and your Python is on the server.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill ... thank you, I'm just starting my journey with GAE+python and just figured it out after ... thank you all